# Shared library in C with two application

Tags: c

In case of a shared library between two applications, does each application use it's own copy of the library during run time ? If they use the same instance of the library, what happens to the global variables inside the library ?

Comment: It depends on how the library is shared, what the operating system is, and so on. But typically for common systems, for separate processes, then there are separate instances that can't share data unless they explicitly take steps to do so, e.g. with memory mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each program creates a new instance of the library in its own memory space.  They are not shared and the 2 programs will not see each other's data.

Take a look at how dynamic libraries are loaded: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries

The same is true for statically linked libraries except instead of being loaded at runtime, they are linked at compile time.

Comment: One nitpick; the same code (the text section) is typically shared among multiple processes only the data section is newly created for each process. Also check out [position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/) from the same blog you mentioned.

Comment: I think from all the answers i have read that they share the text section which mean they dont use tow different instance , i agree with@dfj , so  since it is the oldest answer i will consider it with @djf comment as answer of my question.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct.  I was answering the question of whether the programs will see each others' data without some sort of interprocess communication.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the operating system. On most Unix-like systems, shared libraries use position-independent code, so the memory used by the code segment(which holds instructions and read-only variables) can be shared between processes, but each process still has its own data segment(which holds other variables).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have maybe a reference for further reading please?

Comment: @sansuiso This book doesn't delve into details about memory but provide a memory layout for modern UNIX systems: Advanced Programming in Unix Environment 3rd edition pg 206:
"Shared libraries remove the common library routines from the executable file, instead maintaining a single copy of the library routine somewhere in memory that all processes reference. This reduces the size of each executable file but may add some runtime overhead, either when the program is first executed or the first time each shared library function is called."

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to grab a copy for my education :)

Answer (score 2):

For Unix-like operating systems, when you first execute your applications, the page tables of the two processes which map the library address space will point to the same frames in memory where the library is loaded.

However, the page tables which map the data section of the library are handled with `Copy on Write` mechanism. As soon as you try to write a global variable, the OS will create a process specific copy of the page containing the variable and will remap the page table of the process accordingly.